# Android coding best practices

Tags: java, android, optimization, filenames

I want to check the community opinion about best practices for naming in Android:

- Id name in xml:

  ```
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/addressId" />
  ```

  What's better, to name the ID "addressId" or "address" or maybe "addressTextView"?
- variable naming:

  ```
  TextView addressTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.addressId);
  ```

  The var name here is "addressTextView", and I think it's the best practice, unless there is better practice.
- XML file name

  I used to use snack_case for my XML layout files this way, "activity_home.xml" or "activity_login.xml" for activity and "cell_contact_xml" "cell_address" for custom cell, so is that the best way or there is better?
- Java file name:

  I think here everybody agree to add significant suffix for the class name, and use CamelCase, the best would be like this "HomeActivity" "DetailsFramgment" "ContactAdapter".

Comment: Im calling my id's in this way: activityname_viewname, but tt is more or less a matter of taste. But Post you question better on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: also check this official best practice : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/index.html

Comment: I already checked the android developer site, they are talking about optimization inside the app, not about coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In AOSP ids normally use underscores. `address_id` instead of `addressId`. I have seen attributes use camelCase in AOSP however.
2. That is the best practice. This is from the [Code Style Guidelines for Contributors](https://source.android.com/source/code-style.html) for AOSP:

> Follow Field Naming Conventions
>
> Non-public, non-static field names start with m. Static field names
>   start with s. Other fields start with a lower case letter. Public
>   static final fields (constants) are ALL_CAPS_WITH_UNDERSCORES.

3. Layout files/XMLs are lowercase and use underscores. Your usage is correct.
4. Class names should follow the [naming conventions outlined by Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).

> Class names should be nouns, in mixed case with the first letter of
>   each internal word capitalized. Try to keep your class names simple
>   and descriptive. Use whole words-avoid acronyms and abbreviations
>   (unless the abbreviation is much more widely used than the long form,
>   such as URL or HTML).

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't add "id". there is no need to add id to all of your id's.
Beside that, usually the id's are not camelCase... So if you do want to call it adressId you should have it as "adress_id" and not "adressId".